# Print a PDF converted to Byte Array (Epson ePos)

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, printing, epson

I am using the Epson Epos sdk to print .pdf invoices generated with an external library. The problem is that when I send the invoice to print it prints but in a lot of codes and letters. It does not print the pdf as such. The sdk has a "addCommand" method that receives a "Byte Array" and it doesn't work.

I tried adding the data-type to base64 and then converting it to byte array and it doesn't work either. Can anyone of you have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

**SDK EPSON EPOS** -
**Printer Model TM-T20II**
To reproduce the problem simply choose any pdf and then convert it to bytes and send it with the addCommand function and it will print a bunch of garbled characters.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please make a [mre] so we know what you're doing. It's difficult to tell from the (almost no) information you've provided.

Comment: @Jorn I just added a reproducible example. Likewise the version of the printer. This printer, if it prints pdf files, was verified by sending prints through CUPS and it works. But with the sdk I have not been able to do it directly.

Comment: Are you using flutter to make this ?

Comment: @Hedwin Correct, in flutter I generate the pdf and then send it through the Platform channel and I have a plugin that uses the epos sdk. Everything works, if I try to print text, images, it works. But when I send a pdf the result is as above.

Comment: It seems like it print the raw pdf file like when you open a pdf file with a text editor

Comment: Here is the full documentation of the sdk your using, I have not found a way to print PDF file from it. It seems like you can only print text and images but not full pdf document.
https://thepapertreeacademy.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/epos-print_sdk_android_e_reva.pdf

Comment: @KJ Well, then what I have been able to find out is that it is not possible to send a pdf to an Epson printer with the SDK for android. So I'm going to give up on this and look to create the received ones directly with the SDK functions or perhaps have a cups server on a raspberry pi device and then connect the printer and start printing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for people who may be having the same problem with the Epson SDK for android. I notify you that at this time it is not possible to directly print a pdf file. In order to print you must use all the commands that we have in the SDK, add text, add images, align, etc.. but you cannot send a pdf file directly. To do this, they will have to look for another option, in my case I am going to enable an old raspberry pi and configure it as a print server.